# I can't "override" @NotEmpty message with .properties

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm studying Spring 3 and im trying to validate a form using the class  `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty`.

Im able, for instance, to override the `@Size` message (`javax.validation.constraints.Size`) and the `@Email` message (`org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email`) retrieving the messages from a .properties file.

But im not able to override the `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty` default message. I always get the default message "may not be empty"

this is my XXXX-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>     

      <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
             <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springgestioneerrori.controller" />     

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>    

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" >
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my User class

```
package com.springgestioneerrori.model;    


import javax.validation.constraints.Size;   
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class Utente {


    @NotEmpty 
    @Size(min=3,max=20)
    private String nome;            

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }   

}
```

This is my form

```
.......
<form:form action="formSent" method="post" commandName="utente">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" /><br/><br/>
<spring:message code="form.label.utente.nome"/><form:input path="nome"/><form:errors path="nome" cssClass="error" /><br>  
<input type="submit">
</form:form>
 ......
```

this is my controlller

```
........
    @RequestMapping("/formSent")
    public String formSent(Model model, @Valid Utente utente, BindingResult result){    

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("utente", utente);   
            return "form";
        }
        else{
            model.addAttribute("msg", "inserimento effettuato con successo");
            return "formSent";
        }       
    }
.........
```

this is my propertis file

```
    NotEmpy.utente.nome = il campo nome non può essere vuoto //Im NOT able to get this message
    Size.utente.nome = Il nome deve contenere tra 2 e 30 lettere //Im able to get this message
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a file `ValidationMessages.properties` and place it in the classpath of your application. The Hibernate validator use the `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message` key to translate the message

```
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message=il campo nome non può essere vuoto
```

Have a look here for further information:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation

**UPDATE**

For customizing a single message use something like this:

```
@NotEmpty( message = "{NotEmpy.utente.nome}" )
@Size(min=3,max=20, message = "{Size.utente.nome}")
private String nome;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

@NotEmpty( message = "{NotEmpy.utente.nome}" )
private String nome;

Comment: Thank for your help. I made a very stupid error. Inside the properties file i wrote NotEmpy instead of NotEmpty. Sorry for waisting you time :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your help. I made a very stupid error. Inside the properties file i wrote NotEmpy instead of NotEmpty. Sorry for waisting you time :)