# Spring boot using placeholders in messages.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.1.5, and I'm using javax annotations to validate my class properties. So for example, I have:

```
class MyClass {
   @NotEmpty(message = "{validation.notEmpty}")
   private String company;
}
```

Then I have a `messages.properties` file that contains:

```
validation.notEmpty={0} is missing
```

I was hoping to get the error message "company is missing", but instead I'm getting "{0} is missing". What is the proper way of passing my variable name as placeholder?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934781/i-cant-override-notempty-message-with-properties

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve such a thing because `@NotEmpty` resolves the placeholder and get that value as message, it doesn't pass it to the placeholder to be added as parameter.
Look at [the default message](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/resources/org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages.properties) :

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message        = must not be empty
```

You can just pass a string as value.
Validation messages are not default not designed to hold the field name. That is retrievable from the `ConstraintViolation` objects that provide (among other things) paths for each validation error.

So to achieve your requirement, what you could do is creating a custom annotation/validator with a second attribute :

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{validation.notEmpty}", field="company")
private String company;
```

But doing it for every kind of constraints you use looks an overhead.

Maybe just accept the duplication that is simple to refactor :

```
@NotEmpty(message = "car is missing")
private String company;
```

Note that you loses the benefit from locales, which may be undesirable if you handle multiple languages.
In this case, a more robust approach would be to use `ConstraintViolation`s that has the path value of the field.

If my view doesn't address your issue, I encourage to post the question in the [Hibernate Validator issues tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HV/issues).

Comment: what do you mean to use ConstraintViolations that has the path value of the field?

Comment: Yes it is a way.